# Is this scene from Star Blazers 2199 a reference to Clifford D. Simak's novel The Way Station?

Tags: space-battleship-yamato

[image: Quote]
In episode 1 at around 10 minutes in, we receive this scene, where the Japanese supposedly translates to "Here lies a visitor from a distant star."

I can't help but wonder if this is a reference to [Clifford D. Simak's novel The Way Station](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/636479-here-lies-one-from-a-distant-star-but-the-soil)?

What do you think. Do you know if the date (2199.1.17) shown has any significance?

Comment: Are you asking about "Way Station"? Simak doesn't have a story called "Way Machine". http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6698

Comment: @OrganicMarble stupid typo, thanks for pointing it out. You are right.